# Continuing ASP.NET script execution after data is returned to client

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I am working on a project in which a user will upload a file to the server that will be parsed.

I would like the user to receive a status message when the upload is completed and then for them to be able to poll the server for updates regarding the status of the parsing.

I was thinking to use a ajax file upload in which when the client receives an upload success message from the server it begins polling every 2 seconds for the status. I do not know how to return data to the user while still having the server continue execution of the parser and being able to track the status of that execution.

What is the best way to go about continueing script execution after a view is returned from a controller.

EDIT:

I suspect I may need to spawn another process, but I have no idea how to do this

Comment: you wanna look into SignalR.js or Node.js, or maybe you wanna go fancy and read about [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming))

Comment: [Here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETBackgroundWorker-dda8d7b6/view/SourceCode) is an example on MSDN that does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that in this particular case it would make sense to decouple your file processing from the web request. The ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem approach suggested by C.M. is one option, but you might also want to consider using a real queuing mechanism (like MSMQ or RabbitMQ) and process your uploads in a separate application. This way, your web tier is decoupled from your business processes and you can scale each piece independently if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at SignalR (https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) it's a library for building web web apps with very easy communication between client and server.

If you want to know about how to do background processing you can use threading to spin up a thread that will run even after the webpage has been returned to the user. There are plenty of examples of this on StackOverflow and the web.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way I've seen this done is using the ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem along with a static list that keeps track of the status background threads.